# Dynamic value for wso2 CEP window time

Tags: window, wso2, complex-event-processing

I am trying out WSO2 CEP for our new requirement. Currently i have written a query to find timedout events.

from InputStream#window.time(5 minutes)
select *
insert into TimeoutRequest for expired-events.

But my requirement is, the 5 minutes mentioned in time window will vary from each request. Some request should get timeout in 5 mins and some in 10 minutes. How to pass dynamic value for window.time(n minutes). If we can do via Custom Transformer or Custom Window, i am not getting the right context on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be different approaches to implement this:

1. Custom window - you can write you own window (extending the time window) which looks for a specific attribute in events to determine their timeout durations.
2. If there is only a limited set of time durations, you can simply define a window for each duration and point the incoming events to the relevant window using a filter.
   e.g:

   from InputStream[timeoutValue == 5]#window.time(5 minutes) select * insert into TimeoutRequest for expired-events

   from InputStream[timeoutValue == 10]#window.time(10 minutes) select * insert into TimeoutRequest for expired-events

Comment: Thanks a lot Rajeev, but i am facing the issue to create the Custom window. I copied all the jars from wso2 CEP library to build path for creating the custom class. But unable to locate the classes imported. Can you help on. And also how to get the existing time window class code/how to get source code for wso2 products.

Comment: it'll be easier to create a maven project and add the dependencies there. check this link for the dependencies for CEP 4.0.0 and the required repositories:  https://gist.github.com/rajeev3001/1884a06c274f6928e678